# Альтернатива pythonanywhere с потоками

Tags: многопоточность, flask, pythonanywhere

Мое веб приложение работает во Flask с потоками (Threads). Развернул его на pythonanywhere, но он не поддерживает потоки. Скажите, есть ли альтернатива pythonanywhere с поддержкой threads?
Моё веб приложение получает текст от пользователя, загружает дополнительную информацию из почты гугл через imaplib и отправляет данные в таблицу через google sheet api. Эта процедура занимает время, соответственно, не хочется, чтобы эти 7 секунд пользователь ждал, хотя эти процессы могут выполняться в фоне. Это возможно реализовать без потоков и асинхронности?

Comment: Скорее всего у вашего веб-приложения неправильная архитектура, если ему понадобились потоки

Comment: Моё веб приложение получает текст от пользователя, загружает дополнительную информацию из почты гугл через imaplib и отправляет данные в таблицу через google sheet api. Эта процедура занимает время, соответственно, не хочется, чтобы эти 7 секунд пользователь ждал, хотя эти процессы могут выполняться в фоне. Это возможно реализовать без потоков и асинхронности?

Comment: Да, читайте про асинхронное выполнение задач и про Celery (или про Dramatiq и другие аналоги). Правда, поддержки Celery на pythonanywhere тоже нет, но всё равно ваш вопрос должен звучать примерно как "альтернатива pythonanywhere с поддержкой Celery" :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Сразу очевидный вопрос: знаете ли вы альтернативу pythonanywhere с поддержкой Celery?))

Comment: может быть app engine?

Comment: Так-то обе формулировки вопроса не проходят по правилам Stack Overflow. В любом случае с альтернативами не знаком, app engine тоже не юзал - я просто беру сервер с линуксом и ставлю в нём всё что мне нужно